# KBMMW master detail relationship

Tags: delphi

I have a KBMMWclient with master-detail relationship using ElevateDB on the remote server. When posting data from the client after inserting a new data entry, the indexed field for the detail table won't save - saved as null - even if I try to force the value in the beforepost event. If I manually insert the field value (integer) on the server, the master -detail relationship works fine on the client. Why won't it post the indexed field? All other fields post and resolve fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the setting of UpdateInsertAutoIncFields:boolean on the resolver. It is default false.